# Public/private git clone url?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, url, github

Ok, I know how to use git for the most part, but I've just recently been playing with some github stuff and noticed the public/private url. May I ask what that is about?

I know may not be advanced enough for super user, but I wasn't sure where else to ask this :) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public URLs allow anyone to clone your repo, but they're read-only so you can't push changes back over a public URL. Private URLs are only accessible by collaborators with access to the repo, but they're read/write so you can push changes back into the repo.

Comment: but public allows them to take and play with it, just without push-back ability?

Comment: @jphenow: correct